# How to find sit template name of created site in sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007

there is one site in moss 2007 but i dont know its template.

i want this because i want to create a site of same template.

please help me to find template of this site.

please help me.

following is the URL:
http://v2_sharepoint:2000/SF/cq/Pages/CQDashBoard.aspx

i want to find template for this Site.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, if your Sharepoint farm is running service pack 2 and you have server access, you can run the stsadm preupgradecheck operation and it will output the site template which you can cross reference [here](http://sharepointmadeeasy.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-identify-template-used-to-create.html). You can also append /_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=GetProjSchema to the end of the site URL, as detailed [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/721bec39-2d32-4bbc-9094-a021a0d06dcb), and that will give you the template name to provision a new site as.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do any coding download SharePoint Manager for [SharePoint 2007](http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/22762), navigate to the SPWeb in question and look at the properties. It should have a **WebTemplate** 
property indicating the name of the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SharePoint Spider to go through a site and get all the information.

SharePoint Spider is mentioned here:
http://www.thesharepointmuse.com/category/user-experience/